# What currently available hard drives are compatible with ATA100

Tags: hard-drive, pata

I have to replace a dead hard drive in a friends computer.  It's a pretty old machine with a parallel ATA100 interface on the motherboard.  Will currently available PATA drives be compatible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, any Pata drive will be compatible. There could be a bios limitation of 128-137gb though.

If the bios does not have 48bit Large Block Addressing support, you should stick with a 120gb or smaller drive.

.

Comment: Thats great thanks.  I'll look for a <=120GB then.  They seem pretty pricey compared to their SATA equivalents on the usual retailers.  I guess I'll try ebay.

Comment: Yes price has gone up for the old Pata drives, soon to be extinct.

Comment: Microcenter has good prices...http://www.microcenter.com/search/search_results.phtml?N=4294945772+4294963476&sht=Any&prt=NewProduct&

Answer (score 1):

You could also get a PCI sata controller board and get a smaller SATA drive if the prices worked out as worth it. Even get a SSD for the previous posters size limitations

Answer (score 1):

How about a [SATA to PATA](http://www.google.co.uk/products/catalog?q=sata+ide+adaptor&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&um=1&ie=UTF-8&cid=12743804876027419167&ei=v2wvTezwKsuTjAfZ6pnLCw&sa=X&oi=product_catalog_result&ct=image&resnum=6&ved=0CEUQ8gIwBQ#) adaptor which lets you fit SATA drives to PATA interfaces (and vice versa) - well less than £10 on Ebay etc.

Comment: I did this in an old Athlon XP, and it works fine.